# How do I solve this issue with gethostbyname_r and DBI or DBD::MySQL on FreeBSD?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, freebsd

I have some old perl code which recently stopped working on a FreeBSD box.  The code which fails looks (in simplest form) like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use DBI;

my $datasource = "DBI:mysql:dbname:hostname.domain.com";
my $user = "username";
my $pass = "password";

DBI->connect($datasource, $user, $pass);
```

This fails with the following error:

```
/libexec/ld-elf.so.1: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15: Undefined symbol "gethostbyname_r"
```

If I change the datasource to reference "localhost" the code succeeds.

I've reinstalled mysql-client, DBI, and DBD-mysql from ports; no effect.

Other applications on this server (PHP, command line tools) are able to access mysql databases by hostname without trouble.

Suggestions for how to resolve this?

EDITED TO ADD:  I notice that my box has both `libmysqlclient.so.15` and `libmysqlclient_r.so.15`.  Could the problem be that DBD::mysql is trying to use libmysqlclient when it should be using libmysqlclient_r?  And if so, how to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

A shot in the dark:

gethostbyname**_r** indicates that Perl uses the "reentrant" (also called threaded/multi-threaded) version of the resolver code. Seems something is wrong with that.

When compiling the dependencies from the ports tree you often can switch multi-threadedness on or off. You can change you previous choice with `make config` from each ports application directory.

If you installed binary packages probably there is a version mismatch somewhere in there.

Comment: It sounds reasonable, but I'm not seeing a tunable option like that on any of the relevant ports.

Comment: oh, and I don't use binary packages-- everything compiled from source in ports.

Comment: See the edit at the bottom of my question for a possible lead on this.

Answer (score 1):

'gethostbyname_r' is a GNU extension, and isn't part of the POSIX standard.
Nevertheless, on my Freebsd 7 box, my libc includes it:

```
nm /usr/lib/libc.a | grep gethostbyname_r
00000eb0 T gethostbyname_r
```

Does your libc contains this symbol?

Comment: Yes:

venture# nm /usr/lib/libc.a | grep gethostbyname_r
00000744 T gethostbyname_r

Comment: Then your libmysqlclient is built incorrectly. You should try other peoples' suggestions (recompiling the port, etc.).

Comment: As indicated, I've already recompiled the port several times with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of libmysqlclient is out of date for your operating system version.  Since it's in /usr/local, I assume it's compiled from source rather than installed.  You can probably fix it by recompiling, but you might want to see if there is a supported version of mysql that can be installed through your OSes package manager.

Comment: It's been recompiled without effect, and has been installed from FreeBSD ports, which should indicate it is supported for my OS version.  Also, as mentioned in the question, PHP and command line apps don't have this problem, only perl.

Comment: Are php and perl using the same .so.15, or is perl perhaps linked against an obsolete version?  Perhaps it's perl that needs upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing DBD-mysql from ports after temporarily moving `/usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15` and `/usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a` out of the way (rename it or something). This might force DBD-mysql to link with the `libmysqlclient_r`.

Comment: Unfortunately when I do that, DBD::mysql refuses to install.

Comment: Try again, with libmysqlclient.a a link to libmysqlclient_r.a.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, try adding hostname.domain.com to /etc/hosts, or explicitly looking up the IP address in your Perl code and using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ldd libmysqlclient.so.15
libmysqlclient.so.15:
        libcrypt.so.3 => /lib/libcrypt.so.3 (0x281bf000)
        libm.so.4 => /lib/libm.so.4 (0x281d7000)
        libz.so.3 => /lib/libz.so.3 (0x281ed000)
```

FreeBSD 6.4-p3,  mysql-client installed from ports, reinstall not help with problem ;(

## no libc in ldd output ;(

but mysql compiled correctly:

```
# ldd mysql
mysql:
        libreadline.so.6 => /lib/libreadline.so.6 (0x28089000)
        libncursesw.so.6 => /lib/libncursesw.so.6 (0x280b9000)
        libmysqlclient.so.15 => /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15 (0x28102000)
        libcrypt.so.3 => /lib/libcrypt.so.3 (0x2815c000)
        libz.so.3 => /lib/libz.so.3 (0x28174000)
        libstdc++.so.5 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5 (0x28185000)
        libm.so.4 => /lib/libm.so.4 (0x28250000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x28266000)
        libncurses.so.6 => /lib/libncurses.so.6 (0x2834d000)
```